# Viewing Edit History

Tags: support, edit-history

In the past, whenever I've tried to edit a post, I could view the edit history via a dropdown box. However, since I gained $2000$ reputation, I haven't been able to do this anymore. I know that I can now edit posts without peer review, but surely I should still be able to see previous edits.

> Do I still have the ability to view edit history? If so, how do I access it? If not, why not?

Comment: Clicking the timestamp, e.g., `3 hours ago`, works for me.

Comment: See also: [Link to view the edit history of a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/link-to-view-the-edit-history-of-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Should have been an answer): Click the edit timestamp, i.e., the hyperlinked words following `edited` under the post.